# Conditional Probability Pr(B|(B ∪ C))

Tags: probability

One side of a 6-sided die is marked “0”, two sides are marked “2”, and three sides are marked
“3”. Each side is equally likely to occur when the die is rolled. The die is rolled twice and
the results are recorded.

Let A be the event that the first roll is 0.

Let B be the event that the second roll is 3.

Let C be the event that the sum of the two rolls is 5.

Find Pr(B|(B ∪ C)).

Does this equal to 0.25?

Comment: To clarify, you're using the union symbol to mean "or" here?

Comment: Yes, so I had to find the probability of B occurring, given that B or C occurred.

Comment: perhaps include your working to obtain the value $0.25$?

Comment: Pr(B|(B ∪ C)) = Pr(B ∩ (B ∪ C)) / Pr(B ∪ C) . 
 = Pr( (B∩B) ∪ (B ∩ C)) / Pr(B ∪ C) . 
= Pr(B ∪ (B ∩ C)) / Pr(B ∪ C) --> used addition law to find the numerator . 
= (1/6) / (1/4) . 
= 1/4 . 
Hope its not too confusing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remark about your attempt:

If your working is correct:

$$\frac{(1/6)}{(1/4)}=\frac23$$

Guide:

$$B \cap (B \cup C)= (B \cap B) \cup (B \cap C)=B \cup (B\cap C)=B$$

The whole term is equal to

$$Pr(B|B \cup C)= \frac{Pr(B)}{Pr(B \cup C)}=\frac{Pr(B)}{Pr(B)+Pr(C)-Pr(B\cap C)}$$

Now, you just have to compute $Pr(B), Pr(C), Pr(B \cap C)$.

$Pr(B)=\frac12$, since there are $3$ sides of '$3$'. Try to compute the other quantities.

Comment: remark: in the future, if you have attempted a question, try to post your attempt as well in the original post as well. you get to learn from your mistake and attract more positive responses.